# Using Angular2 router, how can all children of a route load the same component?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My router config looks like this (obviously it doesn't work):

```
{ path: 'category', component: ArticlePageComponent },
{ path: 'category/**', component: ArticlePageComponent }
```

I want the url `www.mysite.com/#/category` and `www.mysite.com/#/category/randomCategoryTitle` to both load the same component, so I need some form of wildcard handling, hence the double stars `category/**`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing the :wildcard

```
{ path: 'category/:catId', component: ArticlePageComponent }
{ path: 'category/:catId/:catTitle', component: ArticlePageComponent }
```

you should see both in your route

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute  ...


this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   console.log(params);    
...
```

Should look like  `{catId : '', catTitle : ''}`